# Largest Fourier coefficient of sparse boolean function

Tags: co.combinatorics, fourier-analysis

Consider a Boolean function $f: GF(2)^n \rightarrow \{0, 1 \}$. I would like to show that if $f$ is sparse, i.e. $\sum f(i) \leq t$, then $f$ must have a large Fourier coefficient. (A Fourier coefficient is defined in the sense of the Walsh-Hadamard transform, $\hat{f} (\gamma) = \sum_i (-1)^{i \cdot \gamma} f(i)$ ).

That is, I want to find some function $F(n,t)$ such that if $\sum f(i) \leq t$, then there is some $\gamma$ with $|f(\gamma)| \geq F(n,t)$.

For example, if $t \leq n$, then there must exist $\gamma$ with $\hat f(\gamma) = n$; for if $x_1, \dots, x_t$ are the non-zero entries of $f$, then simply choose some $\gamma$ which is orthogonal to all of them. Thus, $F(n,t) = n$ for $t < n$.

EDIT: I am aware of the Parseval's identity, but this gives estimates which do not take into account the fact that $f$ is integer-valued. I am primarily interested in the case in which $t$ is quite small, on the order of $n$.

Comment: So $\gamma$ is again in $GF(2)^n$ and $.$ is the standard scalar product?

Comment: Yes, $\gamma \in GF(2)^n$, and this is the standard dot-product.

Comment: Then I don't quite understand - is not always $|\hat f(\gamma)|\le\sum f(i)$? I mean, $\hat f(\gamma)$ is placed between numbers obtained when either each $(-1)^{i\cdot\gamma}$ is $1$, or each of them is $-1$, i. e. between $\pm\sum f(i)$

Comment: I think Tom Sanders considered this question and may have had an argument to show that F(n,cn) > c' 2^n, where c' depends only on c, but I don't remember exactly. I'll ask him. I think this is closely related to the issue of getting a bound on the Sidon constant s(X \cup Y) in terms of s(X) and s(Y) (known, due to work of Rider in the 1970s), together with the fact that a dissociated subset of GF(2)^n is Sidon, where Sidon is in the harmonic analysis sense http://webpages.uidaho.edu/lnguyen/SidonSet_RieszProduct.pdf.

Comment: Tom got back to me. You can indeed get such a bound by considering the (2k)th moment of f^(gamma), for which you can find a lower bound by expanding out combinatorially and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to bound the number of solutions to x_1 + ... + x_k = y_1 + ... + y_k with f(x_i), f(y_j) = 1. Then ignore the term gamma = 0 and optimise by taking k ~ n/c.

Comment: @Ben, Can you please expand on this, and either provide a citation or make it an answer? Thanks a lot

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე -- you are absolutely right, I fixed this in the question.